# Sqlite3 stores data as text instead of integer

Tags: python, sqlite

I have created a table in Sqlite3 as following:

```
def create_table(self):
    """create a database table if it does not exist already"""
    self.cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jobs(title text, \
                                                        job_id integer PRIMARY KEY, 
                                                        age integer)''')
```

"age" is defined as an integer. But when I executed this query in DB Browser for SQLite:

```
Pragma table_info(jobs);
```

I got this response:

```
Query executed successfully: Pragma table_info(jobs); (took 1ms)

cid name type  pk
2   age  text  0 //rows title and job_id have been ignored as they are as expected
```

***"age" is of data type text?!?!***

The possible cause is:

- when a row of data is inserted, the data inserted into age column is of text, but if this is the case, then it comes with one more question, does sqlite3 not check data type before inserting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the issue persist if you drop the table and recreate it? Since you are creating it only if it does not exist, it might be an artifact from an old version.

Results are as expected on my end:

```
0|title|text|0||0
1|job_id|integer|0||1
2|age|integer|0||0
```

Comment: How strange!! I dropped this table and re-executed my program and it worked as expected. The funny thing is: I had dropped my old table before creating a new one, then this issue in my question happened. Have you encountered a similar issue before?

Comment: Not personally, but maybe the old drop didn't succeed or something like that, or maybe you had a different DB open.